# Problem with pbinom in R (and binom.dist() in Excel)

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I understand that the R-function

```
pbinom(0, 100, 0.5, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

returns the probability of getting 0 or more heads in 100 trials. R gives the correct outcome, 1 for this problem. But if I use very small values for the probability in a single trial, as in

```
pbinom(0, 100, 0.0000000001, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

I get an answer close to 0, actually: `1E-08`, while I expected a result close to 1. Is this a bug? A similar thing occurs in Excel. But the propbability of ZERO or more successes in a binomial experiment should always be equal to 1. For the example above it is not important, because I know the answer already, but I am using the function pbinom() in a program.

Comment: This is called "scientific notation": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: I know that! It is close to zero. But that is strange. In 100 trials with a very small propbability p in each trial, I would expect to find a probability close to 1 of finding 0 or more successes

Comment: `lower.tail=FALSE` means that you ask about $P(X > x)$, so about a probability of 1's, that is very small, so the answer is correct.

Comment: I had a sioource which said pbinom(k, n, p, lower.tail=FALSE) yields P(X>=k). That is apparently wrong. Thanks again. Now I want to find out how to grade your accurate answer (I am new to this forum).

Comment: In R you always can look for help using `?pbinom` or `help('pbinom')` in this case they provide a valid reference. As about using this site you can always vote up or down (the triangles pointing up and down) and/or accept the answer if it answers your question (the "v" sign). You can vote for multiple answers and questions, while you can accept only one answer for your question.  See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 6):

Binomial distribution is

$$ \Pr(X = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $$

so with $k = 0$ this becomes

$$ {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = {n\choose 0}p^0(1-p)^{n-0} = 1 \times 1 \times (1-p)^n = (1-p)^n$$

with `lower.tail=FALSE` you ask about $\Pr(X>k)$, so basically for $\Pr(X = 1)$, that is

$$ 1- (1-p)^n = 1 - (1 - 0.0000000001)^{100}$$

what gives you a correct answer. Check it if you want:

```
> 1-(1 - 0.0000000001)^100
[1] 1e-08
```