# Hypothesis testing help

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I need some guidance to the following hypothesis (pardon my poor English and wrong use of technical words)

If 75 marbles were drawn "fairly / blindly" without replacement from a "bag" initially containing exactly 1 million red marbles and exactly 0.1 million black marbles, and 56 of those 75 marbles drawn were black and the remaining were red, then what is the probability (%age) or significance levels (%age) of the hypothesis that that this draw has taken place randomly (without cheating) or alternatively the draw is inconsistent with random selections.

To put the problem in perspective, the red marble is worth, say USD 1, and the black marble is worth USD 1,000 in the market. So there is a significant incentive to draw a black marble by cheating. Is there even a 1% chance that this ratio of 56 blacks in 75 draws is honestly done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard exercise with the binomial distribution. You are asking what is the probability of drawing 56 or more black marbles (given your data and assuming sampling at random). In R:

```
> pbinom(56,75,0.1e6/1.1e6,lower.tail=F)
[1] 7.757749e-44
```

So the probability is practically zero.

**Edit**
I should mention that the above result is not *exactly* correct, because the binomial distribution samples *with replacement*. In your case, since you asked for sampling *without replacement*, what you are really looking for is the hypergeometric distribution. The reason why I didn't use this distribution from the start is that the binomial distribution is a good approximation of the hypergeometric for large samples (plus the binomial distribution is easier to understand). So the correct result is:

```
> phyper(56,0.1e6,1e6,75,0.1e6/1e6,lower.tail=F)
[1] 7.652874e-44
```

You are going to get significant differences only if you decide to sample 5 % or more of your total observations (5 % of 1.1 million in your case), otherwise the results will be very close.

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware about R. I used the the online binomial calculator at https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx but it was not so precise as your function.

Comment: The `pbinom` function is available in the R statistical programming language. You do not really need to use R though, as the formula for the binomial distribution is simple enough, have a look at the answer in this question for the formula and use case https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151764/problem-with-pbinom-in-r-and-binom-dist-in-excel. Also I am sure you can do this in Excel or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone here can devise a better approach but here is a quick and dirty perspective on this question.

A quick simulation (without using "rare event tricks") gives an initial look. Drawing 56 black marbles in this situation seems unlikely (very small but admittedly nonzero probability).

The 99th percentile from this experiment was 13 (black marbles drawn).
[image: Empirical Results]

MATLAB Code (replace `for` with `parfor` for speed if hardware supports)

```
% Setup
NumTrials = 80000; 
NumDraws = 75;
Bag = [zeros(1e6,1); ones(1e5,1)];  % [red; black]
TotalBlack = zeros(NumTrials,1);

% Simulate 
for k = 1:NumTrials
    TotalBlack(k) = sum(randsample(Bag,NumDraws,'false'));
end

% Results
max(TotalBlack)
quantile(TotalBlack,.99)
histogram(TotalBlack,'Normalization','pdf')
```

**NOTE:** The label "Relative Frequency" on the graph is poor wording. It is the estimated probability density.